# document.querySelectorAll.forEach strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I have this small piece of code which manually get the value of checked checkboxes and emit through socket io. The thing is, if I comment out `payload.permission.subscriptionPlans.push(item.value);` it works fine, but if I uncomment it,  socket.emit still run and I still get all the data I needed server side without any errors, but it doesnt run the callback function. Here's the code:

```
let payload = {
  permission: {},
};

payload.permission.subscriptionPlans = [];

document.querySelectorAll(".form-add-sub-plan:checked").forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.value); // this still works
  payload.permission.subscriptionPlans.push(item.value); // problem here
});

socket.emit("admin/manage-permission/create", payload, (res) => {
  let addModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById("add-permission-modal"));

  addModal.hide();

  table.reload();

  table.displayMessage(res.payload.type, res.payload.message);
});
```

```
// server code
socket.on("admin/manage-permission/create", async(req, done) => {
  try {
    if (await Permission.exists({
        url: req.permission.url
      })) {
      return done(
        new SocketPayload("error", 409, {
          type: "danger",
          message: "Url already exists",
        })
      );
    }

    let newPermission = new Permission(req.permission);

    // console.log(newPermission);
    await newPermission.save();

    return done(
      new SocketPayload("success", 200, {
        type: "success",
        message: "New permission was added",
      })
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);

    return done(
      new SocketPayload("error", 500, {
        type: "danger",
        message: "An error occured",
      })
    );
  }
});
```

Any ideas why this happens?
Edit: added server code if anyone is wondering

Comment: The problem is probably in the controller. It may not be responding when the subscription information is fill in.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think that's the problem. My server side code only saves the record and always return an message regard of anything happens even error tho, and in this case it still works, so I think it's client side thing.

Comment: I added server code if that helps

Comment: Check the Network tab of DevTools to see what response you're getting when the callback doesn't run.

Comment: it doesn't give anything, that's the problem.

Comment: Where is `payload.permission.url` in the client?

Comment: Sounds like `newPermission.save()` isn't returning.

Comment: If you don't see a response in Network, then something is failing on the server. Add `console.log()` statements to see where it's stopping.

Comment: I'm looking into it. about the ```url``` there are actually a few more code in between to get the form data but they are not the problem so I didn't include it.

Comment: `forEach()` is probably not relevant, I expect you'll have the same problem if you hard-code something like `payload.permission.subscriptionPlans = ["1", "2"];`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it's mongoose middleware stopping the socket to return a callback. It took me a while to figured out cuz the server did not throw any error.